# Can we dynamically return the whole Enum in java

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to achieve something like the below?

abc.java

```
public enum ABC {
A("a"),
B("b"),
C("c")
}
```

numarical.java

```
public enum num {
One("1"),
Two("2"),
Three("3")
}
```

DetectEnum.java

```
public class DetectEnum {
    ABC abc_enum;
    num 123_enum;
    public **<?>** getEnum(String lang) {
        switch (lang) {
        case "Alpha" :
            alpha();
            break;
            
        default :
            numaric();
            break;
        }
        
    }
    
    public ABC alpha() {
        return abc_enum;
    }
    
    public num numaric() {
        return 123_enum;
    }
    
}
```

what we can have in the place of this **<?>** , meaning what should be the return type here?

Comment: How are callers of `getEnum` expected to use the return value?

Comment: You can just return the `Enum` class

Comment: When your enum types implement the same interface, you can use that interface as return type.

Comment: @ernest_k the caller of getEnum is expecting an Enum itself.